Where did the bleu stripe comes from?
Why is there a blue stripe when I render the animation of the ocean?



Increase the Clip End value of your camera.
Manual quote:
Clip Start and End: The interval in which objects are directly visible. Any objects outside this range still influence the image indirectly, as further light bounces are not clipped.


Ohh so it's because of the clip end. Thanks!
